# Problem creating SOAP message in Websphere

Tags: java, soap, websphere, saaj, websphere-9

I have a piece of code that is trying to create a SOAP message from an XML file using a FileInputStream like so..

`SOAPMessage message = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(null, stream);`

This works fine on our WebSphere (v9) development environment, but when I try to run it on our staging environment I'm getting the following error.

`javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to create message factory for SOAP: Provider com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl not found at javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory.newInstance(MessageFactory.java:127) ~[?:1.8.0-internal]`

Is there anything that could explain the difference in behavior in 2 environments? The WebSphere and Java versions (1.8.0) are identical.

I have also checked whether any shared libraries have been added to the development environment, but so far have found nothing.

Is there any other place I should check to see if there is a difference the class loading?

I tried manually adding saaj-impl (1.4) to the WEB-INF/lib folder of the installed application, but it then threw a NoClassDefFoundError error for class 'org.jvnet.staxex.util.XMLStreamReaderToXMLStreamWriter'